# Does Java NIO support broadcast or multicast?

Tags: java, nio, broadcast, multicast

I am searching if Java NIO implements broadcast. I need to create a peer that sends messages to other peers, using multicast or broadcast. I was searching in the API 1.6, but I don't find anything in the DatagramChannel class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

NIO2 supports multicast, that's in Java 7.

http://javanio.info/filearea/nioserver/WhatsNewNIO2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Before NIO2 you have to make use of all kinds of hacks to make a datagram channel join a multicast group. Not sure how they could have left multicast channels out of NIO1.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use NIO for this, `java.net.MulticastSocket` supports this directly.

But, to completely answer your question, no. You cannot use a `DatagramChannel` because you cannot tell it what socket to use, and there is nothing else even close to what you would need in NIO.